# PDFsharp MigraDoc set height of element

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfsharp, migradoc

Is there a way to set fixed height of an element? Could be a table, row or section. This element is dynamically generated from database and it can have a variable number of rows. I need to do that, because the section below needs to be in a fixed position for print out. I am using WPF v1.31. I know it is not the latest, but it's an addition to a quite old application.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of a `Paragraph` or a table `Row`.

I think you cannot set the height of a `Table` - but that will be the sum of the heights of all rows. Automatic page breaks will make things complicated if a table does not fit a single page.

A `Section` always starts on a new page.

`TextFrame` can be used to place text at a fixed position. Depending on the requirements, this could be simple or complicated.

You can prepare a document to let MigraDoc determine sizes and positions. Then you code can decide whether the items with the fixed position will be on the same page or on a new page.

Here is sample code that shows how to show the progress while creating a PDF:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3172
The same technique can be used to stitch several MigraDoc documents together to create a single PDF. If I understand your requirements correctly, this could be the way to go - without setting the height of any elements.